# Open Windows Schedule Task Gui Properties with command line

Tags: windows, delphi, scheduled-tasks

I'm creating a Delphi component to schedule tasks in Windows using command line from **schtasks**.

**My doubt is**:
After creating the basic skeleton of the task I want to open their properties by the Windows task editor.

I have not found a way to call the properties of a task I created the standard Windows interface.

Maybe someone could help me?

**Image sample:**

[image: Sample task property]

Comment: I am almost certain that UI is not part of the task scheduler API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will probably have to build your own UI and then call the API yourself.

Comment: @Graymatter, thanks. You're right, the command line there is no such option. The JCL / JVCL have an abstraction based on MSTask but has incompatibilities according to the version of Windows.

I believe that I'll have to create your own interface and manipulate the basic aspects of task with command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tests I'll found solution using a Windows API and JCL Abstraction (MsTask.pas).

I made my code based on the example of the link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446830(v=vs.85).aspx

Below the complete example of the method to edit a specific task:

```
Uses MSTask{JCL Abstraction}, ActiveX;

Procedure TForm7.EditTask(ATaskName: String);
Var
  LTask: ITask;
  LSchedulingAgent: ITaskScheduler;
  LOutAux: IInterface;

Var
  LResult: HRESULT;

Begin

  //Get scheduler object
  LResult := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTaskScheduler,
    Nil,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_ITaskScheduler,
    LSchedulingAgent);

  If LResult = S_OK Then
  Begin
    //get task object
    LResult := LSchedulingAgent.Activate(PWideChar(ATaskName), IID_ITask, LOutAux);

    If LResult = S_OK Then
    Begin
      LTask := ITask(LOutAux);
      LTask.EditWorkItem(0, 0);
    End
    Else
      ShowMessage('TaskName not found!');

  End
  Else
    ShowMessage('Error to get scheduler object.');

End;
```

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of, and cannot find, a way to open the specific task in the UI. You can open the task scheduler UI using `taskschd.msc`, but that won't open a specific task.

So I'm afraid you'll have to build some UI yourself. You can use the API then to change the properties. Changing properties can also be done through `schtasks`. It has a couple of command line options, one of them is

```
/Change - Changes the properties of scheduled task.
```

With `schtasks /Change /?` you can get more detailed information about the change argument and which additional arguments you need to specify to change specific task properties. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a parameter that open a GUI.

If you feel brave enough, you may use the [Scheduler API functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446817(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of the `schtasks` command line tool. :)

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I'll do a study and then come back to post my impressions. For now I will not make an answer, because I'm doing a test with the Windows API.